# Convert parameter format

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a parameter `@Tag nvarchar(max)` that comes into my stored procedure like this `'(15000338, 15000339)'`. It can come in with only one value or with two or more values.

How can I convert this to `('15000338','15000339')`?
I have tried using replace but I can't get to the final result that I need.

Comment: Do you want table as a result or string?

Comment: I want a string but I don't want it wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Are you building a dynamic IN clause? If so, you need to be very careful of SQL injection.

Comment: Yes I think so. The line I am looking for will be `WHERE bi.tagId IN @Tag`. However, this will not be available to the public, only to the people in our company.

Comment: OK, as it turns out, I actually need those values put into temporary table instead of into a string (like I previously thought). If I am supposed to re-ask the question in a different post, I can do that too.

Comment: p.s. I'm researching it now.

Comment: REPLACE(REPLACE(@Tag,'(',''),')','')
WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(',',@Tag) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(',',@Tag,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@Tag,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@Tag)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Tag,' ',''),'''(','('''),')''',''')'),',',''', ''')
```

I believe that will do what you want, but again, I'm concerned, based on what it appears you're doing you might be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks and I do appreciate your concern. The people at my company don't know SQL except for my own boss who would not attack us.

Comment: If I asked the wrong question am I allowed to revise it here? I can't get this to work so I would like to try getting this output (instead of the one I asked for). It's the same output minus the parenthesis so like this: '15000338','15000339'. I have been attempting to revise the replace statement that you gave me with no luck.

Comment: P.S. Still trying and getting closer . . .

Comment: I will try this:   `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Tag,'''',''),'(',''''),')',''''),',',''',''')`

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Tag,' ',''),'''(',''''),')''',''''),',',''', ''') does what you want I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with replace:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(max) = '(15000338, 15000339)'
SELECT @s = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, ' ', ''), '(', '('''), ')', ''')'), ',', ''',''')
```

Output:

```
('15000338',' 15000339')
```

Comment: Your output is incorrect, see my answer. You have value 2 as ' 15000339' not '15000339'

Comment: Correct, I didn't notice the space. Thx.